# webapi httppost sending the parameter as object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a webapi method as httppost as shown below. I am trying to make a request using
 fiddler but I cant get param object. It is null if I send the request as shown in the image. what am I doing wrong?

```
  [ActionName("getCustomerByName")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<List<Customer>> GetcustomerByName(object param)
    {

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect `object param` to be?

Does the request body JSON string represent a `Customer` ?

If yes, use `Customer` as the type instead of `object`  eg

```
public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomerByName(Customer param)
```

If no then define a class (Any name) with the same field names as the JSON string you are passing and use that class instead of `object` eg

```
public class QueryArgs
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   // rest of your fields go here
}

public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomerByName(QueryArgs param)
```

Comment: actually reason I used it there are different properties which Customer object itself doesnt have. But my problem was a silly typo. I have just founded out that I was writting contentype rather than content-type. It works when i correct it. :)

Comment: @batmaci fair enough but it much clearer to have well defined classes on your API instead of using `object`